# SML - Finding Reals In A Range

Tags: compare, sml

I have the task of taking a list of `reals` and returning a list containing those elements that are `>= 1.0` and `<= 2.0`,  using `List.filter` with any anonymous function and a list of reals.

I'm unsure of how to check elements against conditions, but this is what I've tried so far

```
filter(fn x => 1.0 <= x <= 2.0) r
```

Where `r` is a list of `reals`. What's a way to `if then else` in an anonymous function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track, but you cannot do `1.0 <= x <= 2.0`.

`1.0 <= x <= 2.0` means `(1.0 <= x) <= 2.0`, so let's say `x = 1.5`, that gives you `(1.0 <= 1.5) <= 2.0`, which is the same as `true <= 2.0`, which makes no sense.

Instead, you need to check both `1.0 <= x` and `x <= 2.0`, using `andalso` to combine the two boolean expressions:

```
1.0 <= x andalso x <= 2.0
```